# C++ - Change object pointed by base class (in an operator oveloading function returning reference to base class)

Tags: c++

I have one abstract class

```
class Abs{
    //...
    public:
    virtual Abs& operator--() = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

and two subclasses

```
class Sub1: public Abs{
    //...
    public:
    Abs& operator--() {return *this} //this is just to prevent
                     //Sub1 to become an abstract class
    void print() {cout<<"Sub1"<<endl;}      
};

class Sub2: public Abs{
    //...
    public:
    Abs& operator--() {...}          //here is an issue
    void print() {cout<<"Sub2"<<endl;}
};
```

Is it somehow possible to overload operator-- in Sub2 so that in main function ptr now pointing to an object of type Sub1?

```
int main()
{
    Abs* ptr;
    Sub2 sub2;
    ptr=&sub2;

    ptr->print(); //this should print "Sub2"

    --(*ptr);

    ptr->print(); //this should print "Sub1"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're requirement is awkward, and the real answer is: rethink what you're trying to do.

What you're basically asking for is a way for a member function to change `this` so that it points on another object (since you can't change an object's type). This is impossible.

A slightly more reasonable solution is to avoid the direct use of polymorphism, and have the pointed object contain a field that will point to either `Sub1` or `Sub2`. Then, have that pointer object direct calls to that field. This way, you can change the effective type you're using without hitting language limitations. Note that the pointed object would not be an `Abs`, of course, but some other type.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you need to dynamically change types based on the activity of an override you need to process it through a return value.  So something like `ptr = --(*ptr)`, though I would not recommend keeping the `--` syntax as it won't follow the standard for that operator and will thus be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at all. In your sample you even do not have any instance of `Sub1` class.

C++ allows casing to base class and with some caution to derived class. C++ does not allow to cast between derivation siblings.